# Do apps need to ask user preference in order to use iCloud for simple data?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, icloud

We are currently working on an app and would like to sync favorites across devices using iCloud. The favorites are fairly lightweight and text only. Do we need to ask the user for permission to use iCloud or can we simply go ahead and use iCloud if available?

I have setup all iCloud syncing code already. So it is more a question about AppStore submission rules. Any experiences?

Comment: afaik: you dont need to ask the user, just use it, if its available

Comment: @meccan This isn't good form, see my answer below in regards to iCloud guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple guidelines state that you should invite the user to use iCloud, and give them the choice as to whether they want to use it or not. ([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW1), see "Prepare Your App to Use iCloud").

As per the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), there isn't a concrete rule that states you **need** to do this, it's more of a guideline and a courtesy. I'd suggest you do though, it provides a better user experience, and happy customers.

**Why should I need permission anyway?**

Users only have a limited amount of storage (typically the 5GB allowance), and it's up to them how it should be used. If all applications decided to use iCloud without permission, it'd be a free-for-all, and space would be eaten up fast.

Comment: Thanks. The guideline is what prompted me to ask the question. I understand the argument, but we are looking at ~300kb max if a user has lots of favorites. I agree with your point though. Will discuss internally. The problem is, that we do not necessarily want to ask the user as soon as he opens the app. Postponing the question is not easy either.